# Google sheets run multiple SQL scripts

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I have multiple tabs in a google sheets document that all have slightly different scripts on each tab for pulling/updating info for that tab. Is there a way i can run all scripts at once to save me individually going into each one and running the script. Thanks

Not tried yet, im not sure if there is a function i can use or if i need a script to run. Im open to all ideas but im sure there must be a way to do this as im not the first one to want to run multiple scrips over multiple tabs at once

Comment: If they now require the sheet to be active, they would have to reference the sheets by their names, instead. Then, there would be a function that would call them. The limit is 06 minutes...

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You are not showing any code, which makes it difficult to answer your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runAll() {
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  yetAnotherFunctionToRun();
  // ...
}
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Comment: ill give it a go and let you know - thank you